# Formulas for $\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration

I have problem in online math test: $\int \frac{5}{x}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$

Now thres my solution: $5\ln|x|+\text{arcctg}(x)+C$

My answer was marked as wrong with this one as correct: $5\ln|x|−\text{arcctg}(x)+C$

In my opinion test is invalid, because i used math formula that made me choose first anwer:
$\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\text{arctg}(x)=-\text{arcctg}(x)$ so both minuses should make plus in final solution. Any calculator that i use shows me solution as $\text{arctg}(x)$ so its hard for me to check which answer is really true.

Comment: @user it should be integral, and i dont really know, that is from formula i have from one site and I want check what peple there think about that

Comment: @user One thing for me is sure, integral for my problm should give two solutions, one with arctg and one with arcctg but im not sure about signs

Comment: is arcctg arc cotangent?

Comment: Sorry I read wrongly at first! Your solution looks fine

Comment: @DavidRaveh arccotangent, so yeah

Comment: @urshuk fix you formula as follows $ \frac{1}{1+x^2}=(\text{arctg}(x))'=-(\text{arcctg}(x))'$

Comment: "arctg" and "arcctg" look very similar. Are you sure the correct solution uses the latter?

Comment: Assuming you wrote down everything right, the test's solution is incorrect. Just differentiate what the test thinks the solution is and you'd see that you won't get the original integrand back.

Comment: @user376343 can i make first block integral instead?

Comment: @Accelerator ahh, totally forgot about this method of validation :D. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right indeed by the [relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_between_trigonometric_functions_and_inverse_trigonometric_functions) among the inverse trigonometric functions, we have

$$\arctan x =\frac\pi 2 - \arctan \frac1x =\frac\pi 2 - \operatorname{arccot}x$$

then

$$\int \frac1{1+x^2} dx =\arctan x+c_1=-\operatorname{arccot}x+c_2$$